# Multiple JFrame instances

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I currently have an application with a single window builder and multiple JFrames. When i move from one jframe to another i use the following code

```
contentPane.setVisible(false);
EditAccountDetails editAccountDetails = new EditAccountDetails("admin");
editAccountDetails.setVisible(true);
```

This creates a new jframe but this doesnt close the old one. This doesnt happen when i move from my windowbuilder to a jframe, because i can close the window builder frame:

```
frame.dispose();
AdminDashboard adminDashboard = new AdminDashboard();
adminDashboard.setVisible(true);
```

I cant close the jframe in the same way, and im assuming i shouldnt have multiple instances of a windowbuilder. How do i fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: `JFrame#dispose` ... although I'd recommend using a `CardLayout` instead

Answer (score 2):

> I cant close the jframe in the same way

Why not?  `dispose` is a method of `JFrame`

> and im assuming i shouldnt have multiple instances of a windowbuilder.

[The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) might provide more information

> How do i fix this issue?

I'd recommend using a `CardLayout` instead, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details.

I'd also recommend not using Window Builder or any other GUI editor into you have a better understanding of how the API works, but that's just me

Comment: *"..recommend not using Window Builder or any other GUI editor into you have a better understanding of how the API works, but that's just me"* Nope. You are not alone there.